# Interpretation of regression results related to demographic similarity

Tags: regression, interpretation

I am researching on studies related to the effects of demographic similarities. However, I found many interesting studies related to demographic dissimilarities and wondering whether I could interpretation the result in the opposite direction.

For instance, an author might find that "the **lower** the similarity between an executive and other members in top management team, the **more likely** that this executive will leave the team"

Could I interpret this finding as "the **higher** the similarity between an executive and other members in top management team, the **less likely** that this executive will leave the team"
Any suggestion on further readings would also be appreciated.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes: in a regression a negative beta means that the dependent variable and the regressors are negatively correlated in the sample (after adjusting for the effect of the other regressors) and you can have both the readings